# Saving embedded child models when saving the parent model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

We have a model with a number of child models:

```
// models/parent.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
    children: DS.hasMany("child")
});

// models/child.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
    parent: DS.belongsTo("parent")
});
```

The serializer for the parent model is set up using the `EmbeddedRecordsMixin` like this:

```
// serializers/parent.js
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
    attrs: {
        children: { embedded: "always" }
    }
});
```

If we call `save` on an instance of the parent model, will the children be marked as saved? Or do we need to call save on each child model from within the parent model adapter?

Also, if we define a child model serializer, will it get used to serialize the children during the parent serialization process? Or will ED use a default serializer?

Comment: Sorry, what have you tried? It seems to me that all these questions can be answered but trying it out and observe the requests being sent

Comment: The requests sent are determined by the adapter (we're using custom adapters as it's a highly non-standard 3rd-party backend) so that wouldn't tell us anything. As for "just try it", yes, that'd be the ideal thing, but I've got other higher-priority things eating all my time at the moment and was hoping someone who already knew this would be able to enlighten me in the meantime!

Answer (score 0):

when I needed to save nested models, I overrode the serializer methods serializeBelongsTo and serializeHasMany to get all information to json and next parsed it on the server side.